# Access report/atlas page from feature in layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, popup, atlas, reports

In QGIS 3.22. I've created an atlas layout from a polygon shapefile layer. What I'd like to do is be able to access the atlas page for a given feature without having to open the layout manager. Some possibilities of what this could look like:

1. create an **automatic popup** of the atlas page upon clicking a feature; this would be great, but I do not think the Identify Features tool settings allows this (it always opens a form) and I do not know if there is another similar tool that could be set to pop up like this.
2. create a **field with a link** to the feature page in the atlas; in this way, I could open the Identify Features form, scroll down to the right field, and click the link to open the atlas page. Seeing as *the atlas is already connected dynamically to the map layout on a feature-by-feature basis,* I suspect it is possible to link to a specific feature page, though I am not sure how.
3. create a **layer action** that opens the feature page. This would also require a link between each feature and its page in the atlas.
4. create a Layout Manager **sidebar or box** where the feature pages are visualized as you click the features. As far as I can tell, this manner of viewing layouts/reports is not currently possible.

If none of these solutions are possible, I suppose a workaround would simply be saving images of each page and having a field link to the image. This is not a desirable solution because it is not dynamic and would need to be updated constantly (and would be much more work to implement).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The identify tool could do what you expect in possibility number 1. It could open the atlas page you click on.

Step by step :

1. Select the layer used as coverage layer
2. Click on the identify tool
3. Right-click on the feature you want to use for atlas. A menu will show up, click on the layer used for atlas and then it let you choose between **Identify** and **Set as atlas feature for Atlas** (as I have only one atlas layout for this layer and the name is "Atlas").

[image]

4. Click on **Set as Atlas Feature for Atlas**. It will open your atlas Layout on with the feature you selected as atlas feature. If the layout is already opened it will change the feature selected for atlas.

[image]

Comment: do you know why not all features have that option (-> the smal arrow in context menu)?

Comment: On the screenshot between point 3 and 4 the identification tool is used with right-click on the map canvas. It does show all the layers that have features that intersect your click position. For some layers there is a ► for other there is not. This ► could mean two things : 1. the layer have several features in the click zone OR 2. the layer have one feature in the click zone but sevral option exist (if an action is defined in the layer OR if the layer is used as covering layer for an atlas).   Sorry if I haven't understood what you mean.

Comment: I figured it out.  The layer of the corresponding feature has to be set as coverage layer in one or more printlayouts.

Comment: It would be great to have the option to open an atlas page without opening the entire layout manager (in a sidebar or small layout box, for example), but I assume this is the best possible solution currently. Thanks @CorentinLemaitre.

Comment: If anybody reading this in the future knows how to accomplish this with links, layer actions, etc, please feel free to add a comment!  Thanks.